# How to use tldextract in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, tld

I am trying to install tldextract on my Google App Engine app but I don't manage to get the .tld_set_snapshot file accessed either locally or once the app is deployed. Here is my app directories structure:

```
static/
templates/
tldextract/
  .tld_set_snapshot
  __init__.py
  tldextract.py
```

I guess it's a silly thing but I couldn't find the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: And how does `tidextract.py` try to read `.tid_set_snapshot`?  Code pls?

Comment: @AlexMartelli the code can be accessed there [tldextract.py](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/blob/master/tldextract/tldextract.py). The issue is that it is not clear to me how tldextract.py reads .tld_set_snapshot.

Comment: Got it -- reads it in a fancy way but does read it.  So is that dot-named file getting uploaded?  (Locally shd be OK, though so I don't understand why your code fails locally...).

Comment: Locally I get the following error: File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 250, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/Users/username/projectname/tldextract/.tld_set_snapshot'

Comment: Does `ls -l /Users/username/projectname/tldextract/.tld_set_snapshot'` say about that file?  If so, then it seems you're running afoul of the `is_file_accessible` check in the `stubs.py` you mention.  I imaging you *have* set `application_readable` in your `app.yaml` for this directory, right? See it at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig .

Comment: ls -l says: `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 username  staff  127075 Dec  5 11:22 .tld_set_snapshot`. Yes, I have set `application_readable` as true.

Comment: Recent issue: https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/issues/106

Comment: Any latest info on how tldextract works on the old google app engine pythong 2.7?